# Reset Bindings in c#

Tags: c#

Here's my code guys. I just created a new class for my receipt. 
This code is for Add button.

```
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbProductName.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQuantity.Text))
        {
            Receipt obj = new Receipt() { Id = order++, ProductName = Convert.ToString(cmbProductName.SelectedItem), Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text), Price = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text) };
            total += obj.Price * obj.Quantity;
            receiptBindingSource.Add(obj);
            receiptBindingSource.MoveLast();
            Clear();           
        }
        txtTotal.Text = String.Format("P{0}", Convert.ToString(total));

    }
```

This one if for new data. but still I can't refresh or reset the data in my receiptBindingSource, if I click on new. the total amount still continue of computing.

```
     private void New() {
        cmbProductName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtPrice.Text = string.Empty;
        txtQuantity.Text = string.Empty;
        txtCustomerName.Text = string.Empty;
        txtCustomerNumber.Text = string.Empty;
        txtTotal.Text = string.Empty;
        txtCash.Text = string.Empty;
        receiptBindingSource.Clear();
    }
```

Anyone can help me how to reset, refresh my receiptBindingSource because I cant add a new data. I need to stop debugging so that I can add new. Please help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line:

```
total += obj.Price * obj.Quantity;
```

You are not resetting the value of `total` anywhere.

Comment: In the method that you have written for reset, set the value of total to zero: total = 0;

Comment: thank you so much mate! it works for me :D thank you thank you thank you!